# Detect changes in current component in Angular >= 6

Tags: javascript, angular

The way I understand it is `ngOnChanges()` is reserved to observe incomming data from parent components and the like.

Say I have a component, how do I detect all the changes (ie. dependent on a input field) inside the component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detonate a change check you can use [detectChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges)